# Extract every nth row of a dataset

Tags: function, macros, sas

I would like to extract all of the nth rows of a data set and then every subsequent 33rd row and store them in a new dataset.

I have a dataset that contains n times 33 estimates appended below each other and I would like to extract all of the estimates `a0` into a dataset called `A0` and then all of the `a1` estimates into a dataset `A1` etc until I have 33 datasets.

I can do this for every element but this takes a lot of code and I would like to simplify it. This is the code that names a dataset then extracts all of the elements into it.

```
data a0;
 set _parest1;
 if mod(_n_,33) = 1;
run;
```

This is a specific problem that is part of a larger issue. I have a number of datasets that contain a 34 estimated parameters (a0,a1...a33) and I would like to take the mean of all of each estimate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `firstobs=` data set option to start on the nth record;

```
data want;
set have(firstobs=10);
if _n_ = 1 then output;
else if mod(_n_,33) = 1 then output;
run;
```

So to loop over this, use a macro.  For example:

```
data test;
do i=1 to 100;
output;
end;
run;

%macro loop_split(n,mod, ds, outPre);
%local i j;
%do i=1 %to &n;
   %let j=%eval(&i-1);
   data &outPre&j;
    set &ds(firstobs=&i);
    if _n_ = 1 then output;
    else if mod(_n_,33) = 1 then output;
   run;
%end;
%mend;

%loop_split(33,33,test,want);
```

I split the `n` and `mod` values as they don't have to be the same, but are in your case.

Comment: Thanks for your speedy answer, unfortunately I have not been clear in what I would like and so have edited my question. In your example you start at 10 and then take the next 2x33 lines but I would like to be able to then start at 11 and take the next 2x33 lines and then 12 and so on. How can I get 33 datasets?

Comment: I see.  You can wrap this in a macro.  Give me a minute and I will edit for you.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an alternate way to do this: the hash of hashes method.  This is pulled largely from Paul Dorfman's paper on the subject, [Data Step Hash Objects as Programming Tools](http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi30/236-30.pdf).

```
data estimates;
  do id = 1 to 50;
    output;
  end;
run;

data _null_;
  if 0 then set estimates;
  length estimate 8;
  if _n_=1 then do;
    declare hash e ();
    declare hash h(ordered:'a');
    h.defineKey('estimate');
    h.defineData('estimate','e');  *this 'e' is the name of the other hash!;
    h.defineDone();
    declare hiter hi('h');
  end;
  do _n_ = 1 by 1 until (eof);
    set estimates end=eof;
    estimate = mod(_n_-1,5);
    rc_h = h.find();
    if rc_h ne 0 then do;
      e = _new_ hash(ordered:'a');
      e.defineKey('estimate','id');
      e.defineData('estimate','id');
      e.defineDone();
      h.replace(); 
    end;
    e.replace();
  end;

 do rc = hi.next () by 0 while ( rc = 0 ) ;
   e.output (dataset: cats('out',estimate)) ;
   rc = hi.next() ;
 end ; 
run;
```

This lets you arbitrarily output any particular number of datasets, which is nice.  Here you replace 5 with 33 and adjust variable names ('estimate' is the estimate number, I calculate it with MOD but maybe you have it already in the dataset, and 'id' is of course whatever your ID is for that row - a row number is fine,`_N_` even - and if you have other data variables (you probably do) you can add them to defineData for `e`.